# Update users location continuously without external Library

Tags: java, android, geolocation, mapbox

I am creating a Navigation application using mapbox. I am struggling with updating the users current location continuously. Currently I am using a class `MyLocation`
to get the users current location.
`originLocation` is defined as `private Location`

Not quite sure what to do. I have tried `locationEngine.requestLocationUpdates();` which does not seem to work.

MyLocation class code: Got the code from [Geolocation post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-on-a/3145655#3145655)

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyLocation {
    Timer timer1;
    LocationManager lm;
    LocationResult locationResult;
    boolean gps_enabled=false;
    boolean network_enabled=false;

    public boolean getLocation(Context context, LocationResult result)
    {
        //I use LocationResult callback class to pass location value from MyLocation to user code.
        locationResult=result;
        if(lm==null)
            lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //exceptions will be thrown if provider is not permitted.
        try{gps_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}
        try{network_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}

        //don't start listeners if no provider is enabled
        if(!gps_enabled && !network_enabled)
            return false;

        if(gps_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerGps);
        if(network_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerNetwork);
        timer1=new Timer();
        timer1.schedule(new GetLastLocation(), 20000);
        return true;
    }

    LocationListener locationListenerGps = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            timer1.cancel();
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    };

    LocationListener locationListenerNetwork = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            timer1.cancel();
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    };

    class GetLastLocation extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
             lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
             lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);

             Location net_loc=null, gps_loc=null;
             if(gps_enabled)
                 gps_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
             if(network_enabled)
                 net_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

             //if there are both values use the latest one
             if(gps_loc!=null && net_loc!=null){
                 if(gps_loc.getTime()>net_loc.getTime())
                     locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
                 else
                     locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
                 return;
             }

             if(gps_loc!=null){
                 locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
                 return;
             }
             if(net_loc!=null){
                 locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
                 return;
             }
             locationResult.gotLocation(null);
        }
    }

    public static abstract class LocationResult{
        public abstract void gotLocation(Location location);
    }
}
```

How I am using the class:

```
@SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")
private void initializeLocationEngine() {
   try{
       locationEngine = new LocationEngineProvider(this).obtainBestLocationEngineAvailable();
       locationEngine.setPriority(LocationEnginePriority.HIGH_ACCURACY);
       locationEngine.activate();
       locationEngine.addLocationEngineListener(this);
       locationEngine.setInterval(0);
       locationEngine.setFastestInterval(500);

       MyLocation.LocationResult locationResult = new 
       MyLocation.LocationResult(){
           @Override
           public void gotLocation(Location location){
               originLocation = location;
           }
       };
       MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation();
       myLocation.getLocation(this, locationResult);
   }catch (Exception e){
       Log.d(TAG, "Error" + e);           
   }
}
```

OnLocationChanged method code:

```
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    try{
        locationEngine = new LocationEngineProvider(this).obtainBestLocationEngineAvailable();
        locationEngine.setPriority(LocationEnginePriority.HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationEngine.activate();
        locationEngine.addLocationEngineListener(this);
        locationEngine.setInterval(0);
        locationEngine.setFastestInterval(500);

        MyLocation.LocationResult locationResult = new MyLocation.LocationResult(){
            @Override
            public void gotLocation(Location location){
                originLocation = location;
            }
        };
        MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation();
        myLocation.getLocation(this, locationResult);
}catch (Exception e){
    Log.d(TAG, "Error" + e);
    Toast.makeText(Home.this,"Error initializeLocationEngine", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to run these location updates while the app is in the foreground? Or running in the background?

Comment: @Silmarilos foreground